# Are php files stored on a web server?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I am trying to learn how to use php via ajax and interact with wamp and databases. I do not understand how this works & it's slowing my progress significantly.

When I hear/read "upload php files to your server", what does that mean? I was under the impression that you included all files (php/js/html/etc) in the same folder locally when putting a website/app/etc online - am I mistaken? Are files stored on server and then initiated when called?

Where should php files (specifically scripts to pull and send information) be located? Not understanding this is bottle-necking my progress greatly, so thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, PHP files should be hosted in a web server.

Comment: and a "web server" is nothing special.   It's just a term for a computer that serves/hosts data/files/services.   You can run Apache or node or some other server daemon/software on you laptop/PC for development...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A server is a Computer with High Specification which  keeps running all time so that anyone can have access anytime.

let us see an Analogy.If you had hands on language's Such as C,C++,Python. You must have heard They are High level Language and need to be converted to machine code before they are Executed.

Similarly when we are on web our web browser only understands HTML (That is How to display data on screen)

PHP is a Scripting language (which means how program will work is decided by PHP)

A Database is location Where You can store Data For latter (PHP my need to access this data for computing eg: check if user is a valid user).

When You create a Website You Want a computer That is available all time (server).But they are expensive so You rent some space from Company such as GoDady ..Now This is like having Your own Computer. Uploding Files to Server Means Putting website Files to Your New Computer.

Now suppose You Want to Access your file on your local computer What you do?

> > C:/myfolder/myfile.php

Similarly on Server 'C' is Your websites Name so if your php file is in myfolder directory on your server.

> > www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/myfile.php

When you request webpage www.myfle.com  it go to the server there it processes Php scripts and sends back only Html components that Browser Understands.

Comment: do tell us the origin of fire.